# Are Pringles an example of anti-de Sitter space?

Tags: metric-spaces

Pringles, the potato chip, have the classic saddle shape of anti-de Sitter space.  They seem to be the perfect teaching example of anti-de Sitter space, but I've never heard Pringles used in examples. Is there a reason why Pringles arn't used in teaching anti-de Sitter space?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space

Comment: I'm not certain pringles have the correct dimension for anti-de-sitter-space.

Comment: Because I doubt talking about Pringles will do much to help people understand the complicated mathematics involved in higher dimensional negatively curved Lorentzian manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pringle is likely closer to a hyperbolic paraboloid (saddle):

[image]

which is described by $z=ay^2-bt^2$.

Whereas, anti-deSitter space is an embedding of the form $y^2-t^2=-\alpha^2$, which is a "quasi-sphere". Both have negative curvature, but other than that they are different.

[image]